# Nuitka on MacOs Sierra

Tags: python, macos, executable

I'm trying to use Nuitka(http://nuitka.net/doc/user-manual.html) with python 2.7 to generate a standalone executable on my MacOs Sierra. I installed Nuitka using pip. 
First, I wanted to test a simple example (test.py) like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
# -*- coding: utf-8

from numpy import array

arr=array([1,2,3])

print(arr)
```

Then, I execute this command to generate the executable:

```
nuitka --standalone --recurse-all test.py
```

Since the code in test.py is simple, I thought that it will take small time to generate an executable. However this took a long time before raising this error:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang-4.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

I need this standalone executable to execute it in a distant server without the need of installing libraries and dependencies.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks

Comment: *"I need this standalone executable to execute it in a distant server without the need of installing libraries and dependencies*" – have you considered Docker?

Comment: And on the other end, have you considered shipping your code with a standalone python like Miniconda? I think this also avoids the notion of Install you want to avoid.

Comment: I do not know these technologies since I'm novice to python

Comment: This is why I want to generate an executable...

Comment: I suggest you use Platypus. I use it and it works fine. Turns my python script into a standalone Mac app. It's available from - https://sveinbjorn.org/platypus          Its free and open source. I'd be happy to walk you thru it but its simple to run.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it and I'll be back.

Comment: I tried Platypus but it doesn't seem to compile the Python – it just includes it and is easily viewable by end user. Or am I missing something?